# '+' (one or more occurrences) not working with 'sed' command

Tags: macos, bash, sed

I'm trying to refine my code by getting rid of unnecessary white spaces, empty lines, and having parentheses balanced with a space in between them, so:

```
    int a = 4;
    if ((a==4) ||   (b==5))

    a++   ;
```

should change to:

```
    int a = 4;
    if ( (a==4) || (b==5) )
    a++ ;
```

It does work for the brackets and empty lines. However, it forgets to reduce the multiple spaces to one space:

```
    int a = 4;
    if ( (a==4) ||   (b==5) )
    a++    ;
```

Here is my script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Script to refine code
    #
    filename=read.txt

    sed 's/((/( (/g' $filename > new.txt
    mv new.txt $filename

    sed 's/))/) )/g' $filename > new.txt
    mv new.txt $filename

    sed 's/ +/ /g' $filename > new.txt
    mv new.txt $filename

    sed '/^$/d' $filename > new.txt
    mv new.txt $filename
```

Also, is there a way to make this script more concise, e.g. removing or reducing the number of commands?

Comment: By the way, in BRE you can use `\{1,\}` instead of `+`

Comment: @cdarke, I don't understand, does that also give u multiple spaces?

Comment: `/ \{1,\}/` means "one or more spaces", yes.

Comment: @cdarke your answer is great. I edited the accepted answer to include your helpful comment!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If you are using **GNU sed** then you need to use `sed -r` which forces `sed` to use extended regular expressions, including the wanted behavior of `+`. See `man sed`:

```
-r, --regexp-extended

       use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

The same holds if you are using **OS X sed**, but then you need to use `sed -E`:

```
-E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions
        rather than basic regular regular expressions (BRE's).
```

Comment: -r seemed to be an illegal option but I did a man sed for use of extended regular expressions and it showed up '-E'. Tried it and Bingo! it worked! Thanks! But I'm confused now, the use of '*' worked but for the use of '+' I had to use the -E flag?

Comment: Am I correct in that you are using OS X? `-r` works for `GNU sed`, but `OS X sed` indeed needs `-E` to use the extended (modern) regular expressions. Both make a distinction between _basic_ and _modern_ regular expressions and `+` is interpreted as a ordinary character in the _basic_ functioning of `sed`. See [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format): _Obsolete (''basic'') regular expressions differ in several respects (...) '+' and '?' are ordinary characters (...)_.

Comment: Yeh use -E for OSX instead of -r

Comment: If you use homebrew on OS X, you can install the GNU version of sed (`gnu-sed`) and use the `gsed` command to emulate the normal behavior. (I do this to avoid having to learn the different behaviors of UNIX/BSD sed)

Comment: Isn't it great how every single *nix tool has a different regex engine

Comment: @ThorSummoner: not just *nix, include the .Net engine, JavaScript, Perl (which is now different to PCRE), Python, Java, etc...  See http://choonsiong.com/public/books/Regular%20Expressions%20Cookbook%202nd.pdf

Comment: Accepted answer should be the one suggesting `\+` below because `-r/-E` arguments come with a lot of side consequences. Switching to extended regular expression would fix the `+` problem but it often will break other parts of the original expression. What about the parenthesis in the example code? Don't they have to be escaped now, when `-r/-E` is used? I think that the `()` vs. `\(\)` meaning switches along with extended regular expression on/off.

Answer (score 26):

You have to preceed `+` with a `\`, otherwise `sed` tries to match the character `+` itself.

To make the script "smarter", you can accumulate all the expressions in one sed:

```
sed -e 's/((/( (/g' -e 's/))/) )/g' -e 's/ \+/ /g' -e '/^$/d' $filename > new.txt
```

Some implementations of `sed` even support the `-i` option that enables changing the file *in place*.

Comment: preceding with \ didn't work..  
    -i flag gives the error:  
    sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: the accumulation doesn't work :( I couldn't find how to next sed commands online, is using 'awk' a better option? if so how?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: @Siddhartha: `-i` only works with files, not with stdin. How could you change stdin in place? You could also try semicolons for accumulation: `sed -e 's///;s///;...'`

Comment: Ok so I got the accumulation to work, but I can't get the -E flag to fit in anywhere!:

Comment: sed -e 's/((/( (/g' -e 's/))/) )/g' -e 's/ +/ /g' -e '/^$/d' $filename > new.txt

Comment: I don't think MacOS `sed` supports multiple `-e` options.  Use semicolons or newlines between the individual script commands, and put them all in a single quoted string.  Also on MacOS the `-i` option needs an argument; you can pass it an empty string if you don't want a backup.  So `sed -i '' -E 's///;s///;...' "$filename"`

Comment: This is the best answer. Using `-r/-E` just to avoid one `\`, suggested above, is like going to kill a mosquito with a bazooka. Moreover, more problems could be easily introduced than solved.

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes, -r and -e won't work.
I'm using sed version 4.2.1 and they aren't working for me at all.

A quick hack is to use the * operator instead.
So let's say we want to replace all redundant space characters with a single space:
We'd like to do:

```
sed 's/ +/ /'
```

But we can use this instead:

```
sed 's/  */ /'
```

(note the double-space)

Comment: This is what I've always used in its place.  It works with everything.  It's not really a hack, just a modification of "zero or more" - "one plus zero or more" = "one or more"

Answer (score 5):

May not be the cleanest solution. But if you want to avoid `-E` and `-r` to remain compatible with both versions of sed, you can do a repeat character `cc*` - that's 1 `c` then 0 or more `c`'s `==` 1 or more `c`'s.

Or just use the BRE syntax, as suggested by [@cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736308/cdarke), to match a specific number or patterns`c\{1,\}`. The second number after the comma is excluded to mean 1 or more.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e ':a' -e 's/\([()]\)\1/\1 \1/g' -e 'ta' -e 's/  */ /g' $filename >new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

on the bash front;

First I made a script test.sh

cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
    SRC=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    DEST=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "moving $SRC to $DEST"
    mv $SRC $DEST || echo "move $SRC to $DEST failed" && exit 1
done < "$1"
```

then we make a data file and a test file aaa.txt

```
cat aaa.txt
<tag1>19</tag1>
<tag2>2</tag2>
<tag3>-12</tag3>
<tag4>37</tag4>
<tag5>-41</tag5>
```

then test and show results.

```
bash test.sh list.txt 
Text read from file: aaa.txt bbb.txt
moving aaa.txt to bbb.txt
```